# Сравнить даты PHP

Tags: php

```
    <?
$key = $_GET['key'];
$database = mysqli_select_db($link,"user514_ftkeys");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ftkeys WHERE ftkey = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$key) ."'" ;
$result = $link->query($sql);
$current_datetime = date('Y-m-d');

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

}


if ($result->num_rows > 0 && strtotime($current_datetime) > strtotime($row['expire'])) {
        print "success=1";
    } else {
        print "success=0";
}
```

Но при сравнении 0000-00-00 и 2019-01-03 выдает success=1
Смотрел в соседних темах, ничего не понял :(

Comment: strtotime('0000-00-00') > strtotime('2019-01-03') выдаст success=0. Уверены что в $row['expire'] прилетает то что нужно?

Comment: 2019-01-03 - $current_datetime
0000-00-00 - $row['expire']
success=1 в итоге :0

Comment: 1546473600
-62169984000 и всё равно выдает success=1

Comment: Числа то посмотрите, совсем разные. Может в миллисекундах возвращается? date('Y-m-d', 62169984000/1000) = 1971-12-21 Проверьте данные все. И почему условие проверки не внутри while?

Comment: @holden321 Разделив на 1000 выдает 62121600.

Comment: Попробывал сравнить как строки, но там вообще ничего не работает, странно.

Comment: Разберитесь как работает ваш код в целом и функции php и все станет ясно.